# How these two arrays will be saved in memory?

Tags: assembly, label

Im studying Assembley Language. Lets say that I have two arrays:

list1 BYTE 00h,10h,20h,30h
list2 WORD 0000h,0010h,0020h,0030h

list1 will be saved in memory as: 00,10,20,30

But will list2 be saved as: 00,00,10,00,20,00,30,00 (Am I right here?)

And while reading data from these two lists, will the data be read in little endian format ?

Comment: What CPU architecture are you targeting?

Comment: In that case, the data will be read in little endian format and list2 will indeed be saved as 00, 00, 10, 00, 20, 00 etc.

Comment: @user3356, that's the answer: you should post it as such.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the Intel Conventions
When a word is loaded from RAM or stored to RAM, the lower byte is on the lower offset. (reverse)